# I want p-values in cor() using R

Tags: r

I have two data frame, one with 6 variables and one with 7 variables, I used the cor(data1,data2) to validate the correlation between two data.However, results are  correlation coefficient, but i want the p-values. so who can help me with this problem, thank you very much!

Comment: See `cor.test`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you got two different dataframe to find correlation, it seems that you need `corr_result = corr.test(df1, df2, method = ...)` from `psych`package.
you can get p-value matrix by using `corr_result$p`

here is the document: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/psych/versions/1.8.4/topics/corr.test